# Downloaded and pre-rigged model is partially invisible in object mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

So my friend send a model of his for me to work with, but when I open it the model is partially invisible and the bones are closer together.

[image]

But in edit mode the entire model is visible

[image]
[image]

I've had this problem with other downloaded models but usually higher quality ones.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hehe, I just had to press the "Reload Trusted" button on the top.